# Anyway to highlight and select data in Chrome dev tools sources tab scope sidebar via chrome extension?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

chrome.devtools.panels.sources Seems to be the api of choice here.

Specifically the onSelectionChanged.addListener function.

The problem is this function works everywhere but the sidebars where the debugger data is located.

Is this a joke? Why would google expose an api to modify the debugger UI without also exposing access to its values?

I must be missing something here right?

Specifically I want to select a value in the scope sidebar that appears during debugging, and then run a function on that value that transforms it and displays the transformed value within a tooltip or popup.

I briefly considered the chrome.debugger api but it is mutually exclusive with an open dev tools instance. It’s for “remote” debugging.

Comment: This event is for **text selection** change in the sources editor. There's no way to do what you want other than building a modified devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the reply. Anyway I can write a context script that gets the document of the inspector itself for text selection?  Something like document.getSelection().toString().  Also do you know why the debugger data is protected?  I read something about security issues.  Maybe bc extensions could then read variables in proprietary code?

Comment: content script I mean.

Comment: No, the only methods allowed for extensions are the exposed events like this one.